# Can't render django-comment form

Tags: django, django-comments

Can someone see what I am doing wrong here? What am I missing?

```
# works
{% get_comment_count for app.somemodel object_pk as comment_count %}
{% get_comment_count for model as comment_count %}

# Throws error: "Caught AttributeError while rendering: 'str' object has no attribute '_meta'"
{% render_comment_list for app.somemodel %}
{% render_comment_form for app.somemodel %}

# Gives an empty form and empty list
{% render_comment_list for model %}
{% render_comment_form for model %}
```

the view:

```
# view.py
from app.models import SomeModel

def some_view(request):

    return render_to_response("app/some_template.html", {'model': SomeModel})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never used the comments framework, but I'm gonna go ahead and suggest passing in a model **instance** -- how can you render a comment form or list for a model Class?

Comments have a generic relation towards a model and its ID. You can't comment on a model class.

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/comments/#displaying-the-comment-post-form

```
def some_view(request):
    # pass in an instance, not a class, if you want to render a comment form
    return render_to_response("app/some_template.html", {'model': SomeModel.objects.latest('id')})
```